# Sum of IID Chi Square Random Variables Approximation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can someone explain why and how the following is true?

Let us say we have $n$ IID Chi-square random variables $X_i \sim \chi^2(2) \ ; i=1,\cdots,n$, and $Z := \sum_i X_i$, then $$\Pr\left\{ Z < a\right\} = \Pr\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i < a\right\} \geq \left(\Pr\left\{X_1 < a\right\}\right)^ n .$$

---

From the discussion below: The above inequality is not true. It should be 
$$\Pr\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i < a\right\} \leq \left(\Pr\left\{X_1 < a\right\}\right)^ n .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from definition $X_i$ are nonnegative, $\sum_i X_i <a$ implies each $X_i<a$ and then you can use the fact that they are independent to provw the inequality.

That means $\{\sum_i X_i<a \}\subset \cap_i\{X_i<a\}$ and we can take their measures and use independence of these events $\{X_i<a\}$

Comment: That works only for the maximum of a sequence. Each $X_i<a$ does not imply the sum is smaller than $a$.

Comment: Oh you are definitely right

Comment: It seems my argument proved the another direction.. is the queation flawed?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The inequality in the question should be a $``\le"$.

Comment: I was not able to understand why this is true. I think there is an error in the book. I found this inequality in a book (eq. 8.127): D. Tse and P. Viswanath "Fundamentals of Wireless Communications".

Comment: I have edited my answer and the inequality sign should be reversed. the book has an error.